# No inserta a una BD Mysql desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
require_once 'conexion.php';
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=md5($_POST['clave']);

$telefono="0";
$email="0";

$query1="INSERT INTO usuarios_android 
(nombre, email, telefono, pass) 
VALUES 
('".$usuario."','".$email."','".$telefono."','".$clave."')";

$resultado0=$mysql->query($query1);
if($mysql->affected_rows > 0){
    echo "exitoso0";
} else {
    echo "fallo0";
}

$query="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' and clave='".$clave."'";
$resultado=$mysql->query($query);
if($mysql->affected_rows > 0){
    echo "exitoso";
} else {
    echo "fallo";
}
$resultado0->close();
$resultado->close();
$mysql->close();
```

el cual al hacer un envio me envia la siguiente informacion (estoy enviando usuario y clave correctos)

fallo0exitoso

lo que estoy intentando es que me guarde en la tabla usuarios_android las variables que defini mas arriba, pero por mas que lo intento no lo hace, si pudieran ayudarme a ver que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias

Comment: Y si ademas de todo eso, agregas el error que te esta dando? porque que pongas error, no te dice nada a vos ni a nadie.. si vemos el error, podemos decir cual es el problema...

Comment: Por lo general, yo coloco solo las variables entre comillas simples. Ej: ('$usuario', '$email', '$telefono', '$clave')

Comment: Buenas, Johan, bienvenido al sitio. Dos apuntes: (1) En lugar de tus textos "fallo0" y "exitoso", en caso de error deberías intentar escribir el posible error que estará dando la base de datos. (2) Deberías usar sentencias preparadas para evitar inyecciones SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Para determinar cuál es el error que está sucediendo al insertar (al menos eso puede saberse de tu pregunta), sustituye el mensaje "fallo0" por

`"Error: " . $mysql->error;`